# Uninstall php from fedora 24

Tags: php

I want to uninstall php from my VM that is Fedora 24
Php version is 5.6.31(cli)
I tried the following commands to uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove php
```

Above gave the output as:

> Reading Package Lists... Done
>   Building Dependency Tree... Done
>   E: Couldn't find package php5

I have tried another command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove php
```

But it also didn't work
Please help

And Sorry if I misstated anything I am new to Linux

Comment: It might be possible you have a slightly different package name. Run the following to see which PHP-packets are installed: `dpkg -l | grep php`.
It will probably be named "php5.6-cli".

Comment: have you tried a `yum list "*php*"` to see what php packages are still installed?

Comment: Fedora uses dnf, have a look https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Removing.html

Comment: @matiit yes I have tried the `dnf remove` as well but it didn't worked for me

Comment: @TobiasF. then what command will be for uninstalling php from Fedora 24

Comment: @wodka I have tried to list down the packages for php and it gave long list of packages

Comment: @DeekshaAggarwal can you list the packages in your question? most likely you will just have to uninstall a different package

Comment: I can list a few as it gave a long list

Comment: @wodka
php.x86_64
php-cli.x86_64
php-common.x86_64
php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64

Comment: what about trying delete with a wildcard? ie `yum uninstall php*`

Comment: I used dnf remove command with wild card and it worked for me. Thank you @wodka for giving idea of wildcard

Comment: @wodka is it possible to upgrade php version? Rather than deleting older first and then installing new php and it modules. (Fedora 30)

Actually php version on my system is very old. I've install many modules. I wanna save then because I don't remember all modules name and there purposes. But I wanna also upgrade my php version to latest one.

Thanks in Advance,